# Add leaftlet map to twig template

Tags: leaflet

To include leaflet library in my twig I added the code below in assets/js/app.js

```
import L from "leaflet";
import 'devbridge-autocomplete';

// Pour une raison obscure, lorsque nous utilisons Webpack, nous devons redéfinir les icons
delete L.Icon.Default.prototype._getIconUrl;
L.Icon.Default.mergeOptions({
    iconRetinaUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon-2x.png'),
    iconUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'),
    shadowUrl: require('leaflet/dist/images/marker-shadow.png'),
});

require('leaflet-easybutton');
require('@ansur/leaflet-pulse-icon');
require ('../scss/map.scss');
class Map {
    init(mapId, center = [45.5, 2], zoom = 5) {
        this.map = L.map(mapId, { center: center, zoom: zoom });
        L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
            attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }).addTo(this.map);
    }
}

export default Map;
```

map.scss page contains :

```
// assets/scss/map.scss
@import "~boosted";
@import "~leaflet";
@import "~@ansur/leaflet-pulse-icon/dist/L.Icon.Pulse.css";

#map {
  height: 500px;
}
```

And finally I have the rendered template :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block title %}map{% endblock %}
{% block breadcrumb_second %}
{% endblock breadcrumb_second %}
{% block body %}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-10">
                <div id="map"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <input type="text" name="address" id="address" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

When I refresh my page I don't see the map. I don't know if some code is missed ?

FYI : I run npm watch command.

Thank you in advanced :)

Comment: nothing in your twig template loads the js - it it loaded in base.html.twig?

Comment: This has nothing to do with twig nor symfony. Please post the generated HTML

Comment: @IanMcL Yes js files are generated in base.html.twig and when I click on F12 => Network I have app.js with leaflet added code like 
this.map = leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3___default().map(mapId, {
                        center: center,
                        zoom: zoom
                    });

Comment: What instantiates the Map class? You've declared the class but I don't see anything using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to declare a Map class in assets/js/app.js and you are exporting it for nothing else to use. Instead of declaring a class, just set up Leaflet.js like:

```
if (document.getElementById('map')) {
   let map;
   //set up the Leaflet.js map
   map = L.map('map', /* initial position etc */);
   // tiles etc
}
```

Comment: I removed Map class and replace it by your code in app.js and it works but when I move your code to my twig it doesn't work :( I added parent() function before your code to get imported js and I had this error :  Uncaught ReferenceError: L is not defined

Comment: There isn't a good reason to put the js in your twig, you're already loading it from a js file with an established build process - which is a much better thing to do.